# Are there defined standards for argument sequence?

Tags: functions

Say I have a function taking three arguments:

a symbol (an alias for a class, method or function name)
a mirror/reflection of a specific object
a mirror/reflection of a class in general

is there a how-to (e.g. for certain languages or libraries) to sort things in function calls to keep an API consistent?

Comment: Not 'concise', but 'consistent'. No, there aren't any general standards, but it i still very important that your API stays consistent **with itself**. Pick an ordering and stick to it, your users will thnk you for it.

Comment: For certain kinds of function there may be a standard used by your platform, framework or language which it may be wise to follow. For example, the .net framework has a standardized parameter order for event handling functions; while you don't have to follow it when setting up your own event types, it's certainly a good idea.

Comment: @Kilian: thanks for the concise <-> consistent hint; @-1 at least write why you have given a downvote, it's pretty lame otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That pretty much depends on your API / environment.

A few rules and guidelines that I know of:

- In general: *POLA - Principle of Least Astonishment* (first brought to Computer Science by Mike Colishaw in his book the Rexx Programming Language), also known as *Rule of Least Surprise* - try to think from an API user's perspective, how is it easy to remember? How is it natural to read? Avoid astonishment / surprise.
- Place cohesive arguments together. Example: In `arraycopy(src, srcOffset, dst, dstOffest, length)`, `src` and `srcOffset` are very cohesive, so they stay together. `length` is also cohesive to `src`, but it is equally cohesive to `dst`, which makes the cohesion less specific, therefore it comes last.
- Place the primary object first, i.e. the object that would be a `this` reference in an OO language. In other words: Place the object "to which the operation is told" first.
- Place the *destination* before the *source* (C and similar languages).
- Place the *source* / *input* before the *destination* / *output* (Java and similar languages).
- Place those arguments that are more likely to vary between similar function calls more to the right, those arguments that are more likely to stay the same more to the left.
- Place the parameters with more generic meaning more to the left, the ones with more specific meaning more to the right. For example: `(directory, file)` is usually more logical than `(file, directory)` - unless `directory` is a destination. Or `class, object` usually is more logical than `object, class` - unless `object` is of `this` nature.
- Try to make the calls read (almost) like well-written prose.

And a few hints:

- Be consistent within your API.
- Make it easy for users which already know similar APIs, i.e. look around. If you develop a Qt extension, look how the Qt API itself feels. If you develop a Java API, look how the SUN / Oracle Java API looks and feels.

A few more examples:

- If a function takes an array, an offset into that array, and a length, the sequence should be `(array, offset, length)` because that's how you think: First what, then the details, and the details in the sequence in which they matter. The contract is probably about iteration which we expect to start at `offset` and run until `length` is reached.

In your case it depends on the nature of the symbol, the object and the class. If I assume that object is a member of class, and symbol is a member of object, I would probably expect the sequence to be `(class, object, symbol)`.